# UITabBar Disappears When Switching to Three20 TTThumbnail View

Tags: iphone, three20, uitabbar

I have an application with a UITabBar. I have implemented a Photo Gallery using Three20. Everything is "working fine" except that when I switch to the Photo Gallery, the TabBar dissappears.

I am guessing I am going to have to go into the Three20 code and make some sort of modifications.

Any idea if my assumption is correct and / or what changes I should be looking to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes your assumption is correct, and i would look to change in the Three20UI project, under Photos>Thumbs Controller> TTThumbsViewController.m in the initializers (specifically the one you use), change `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` to `NO` and hope that does it :).

Good luck!

Comment: Wow it will be great if that is all it takes. Will work on it tonight and report back.

Comment: That quickly solved the tabbar problem. Now trying to figure out how to change the NavBar color.

Comment: thats going to be in more places, and not quite as easy... id try to see if they subclass the navbar somewhere...not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the addition question in the previous comment -

For the NavBar colour you need to set `navigationBarTintColor`, and for opaque/translucent you can set `navigationBarStyle`.  Both of these are properties of the TTBaseViewController that itself is a subclass of UIViewController.